# SuiteScript Saving Creditcard to Customer Fails On Expire Date

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am trying to save some customer details to a customer record. I have created this method but it fails when I get to putting in the expire date.

```
function addCreditCard(rec, data){
    rec.selectNewLine({
        sublistId: 'creditcards',
    });
    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId   : 'creditcards',
        fieldId     : 'paymentmethod',
        value       : data.paymentmethod
    });
    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId   : 'creditcards',
        fieldId     : 'ccnumber',
        value       : data.ccnumber
    });
    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId   : 'creditcards',
        fieldId     : 'ccname',
        value       : data.ccname
    });
    log.debug("CC Expire Date", "'" + data.ccexpiredate + "'")
    rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId   : 'creditcards',
        fieldId     : 'ccexpiredate',
        value       : data.ccexpiredate
    });
    rec.commitLine({
        sublistId: 'creditcards'
    });
}
```

The error I am recieving is

```
{
    "type": "error.SuiteScriptError",
    "name": "INVALID_FLD_VALUE",
    "message": "You have entered an Invalid Field Value 08/2023 for the following field: ccexpiredate",
    "stack": [
        REDACTED
    ],
    "cause": {
        "type": "intenal error",
        "code": "INVALID_FLD_VALUE",
        "details": "You have entered an Invalid Field Value 08/2023 for the following field: ccexpiredate",
        "userEvent": null,
        "stackTrace": [
            REDACTED
        ],
        "notifyOff": false
    },
    "id": "",
    "notifyOff": false,
    "userFacing": true
}
```

I can see that a credit card saved into NetSuite is in the format MM/YYYY and in the NetSuite help files I can see it's a string field. What am I missing? Why won't my expire date save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working you need to format the date to one that is accepted by Netsuite. The **'N/format'** module helps with that.

```js
format.parse(expirationDate, format.Type.MMYYDATE)
```

The above returns the Date object and please note that SuiteScript record browser outlines that the *ccexpiredate* field is of **mmyydate** type and (is not clear whether it accepts String or Date object) but the code above works for it. I had a similar issue some time ago so and that code helped me to solve the issue. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks I will try it once the project comes back up for development. It's currently been pushed back for a couple of days. I'll let you know :)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for saving me XD

Comment: To clarify, I put the date in as a string 'MM/YYYY' into the suggested format method and everything worked as expected

Comment: Good news. Thank you for the clarification. Hopefully, this would help others who face the same issue.